# batch script for loop teminates the batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, termination

I'm trying to use for loop and read contents of a file line by line
the file is an xml 
and contains urls and paths delimited by `<>`

I am using the following code

```
set @LOGFILE=F:\nircmd\hosts.xml
:loop
for /F "tokens=2-3 delims=<>" %%a in (%LOGFILE%)do echo "it works"
timeout /t
goto :loop
```

the batch is terminating as soon as it encounters the for loop

i have already tried to pause or timeout the batch 
but nothing seems to work
batch is anyway terminating

what to do?

Comment: basic troubleshooting: a) don't run with doubleclick, but manally from `cmd` to keep the window open, so you can see the errormessages. b) run it with `echo on` to see what exactly is being executed.

Comment: i tried it it halts at loop at once and then terminates the batch

Answer (score 1):

That is because there is no variable `LOGFILE`; you named your variable `@LOGFILE`. Thus the `for` loop encounters an error because it cannot find the file to read and errors such as these terminate the batch file. So either use

```
for /F "tokens=2-3 delims=<>" %%a in (%@LOGFILE%)
```

or

```
set LOGFILE=F:\nircmd\hosts.xml
```

Comment: yeah it works but when i pass the same echo in parenthesis after do , it is again terminating